# Suggest me best validation package for API in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, laravel, mongodb, validation, express

I previously works in laravel and inbuilt library of laravel is very efficient for handle all kind of errors. is ther any library in node also which handle most of errors with proper code structure - 
I don't like code structure like below -

```
check('price').not().isEmpty().withMessage('must not empty').isInt().withMessage("Must be a Integer")
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I have used **Expect npm library** many times & I find it much easier to use. There are lots of built in functions that make your work easy. https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect.html
https://www.npmjs.com/package/expect

Secondly, If you're using it for DB Operations, mongoose provides all kinds of validations you want to use before inserting data. Check it out below:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for you is "swagger". If you write API using swagger, you don't need to write any validation logic at all. In swagger, you can define validations in the configuration file. Swagger will automatically check incoming request, if it is not a valid request then it will reject the request and send bad request response to the client. This is the best article to follow - https://scotch.io/tutorials/speed-up-your-restful-api-development-in-node-js-with-swagger

Answer (score 0):

I like Indicative - https://indicative.adonisjs.com/
It uses declarative validation so it avoids the chaining in your example.

```
const { validateAll } = require('indicative');
const validations = {
    title: 'required|min:1|max:100'
}
validateAll(req.body, validations)
            .then(() => {
                // valid
            })
            .catch(errors => {
                res.json(errors);
            })
```